# React native Xiaomi Phone axios not working

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, mobile-application, xiaomi

We developed an application with react native.
I will leave the link of the application below, I do not know if this is prohibited.
I pull data with axios, it works on all android devices. But it doesn't work on Xiaomi phones. I could not find the reason for this.

```js
const api = "apiadress/deneme.php?lesid="+getLessonId;
axios.get(api).then((response)=>{
    db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql('UPDATE lessons SET downloaded=? WHERE id=?', ['1',getLessonId]);
    });
    response.data.map((item) => {
        db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO questions (questionname,lessonname,answerbame,aoptionname,boptionname,coptionname,doptionname,eoptionname,lessonid,oldidq) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', 
            [item.QuestionName,item.LessonName,item.AnswerName,item.AOption,item.BOption,item.COption,item.DOption,item.EOption,item.id,item.Id]);
        });
    });
    console.log("Tüm sorular başarıyla kayıt edildi.");
});
```

An image of the code
[image: An image of the code]

[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aofsoruapp)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the problem, but I had the a similar problem with axios (server requests didn't work after deployment)

You should consider leave axios and try using fetch:

POST:

```
fetch('http://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        // Authorization: "Bearer " + Token,
        Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
       // sending data userID username, password, etc
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
       // Response will here
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
```

GET:

```
fetch('http://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
       // Authorization: "Bearer " + Token,
       // OR USER name PASSworrd
       Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        // Response will here
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
```